# Can I stop java from telling the macOS window manager to take focus away from my current window?

Tags: java, macos

I am executing a shell script that executes a series of java commands. But the problem exists even if I execute java from the command line. The bottom line is that java changes the application menu bar but other commands (e.g., ls, rm, mv) do not behave like that.

While the script is running, I change my window focus to something else. Every time the script executes java, the window manager takes focus away from my current window and gives it to java (whereby the macOS current-application-menubar appearance reflects the java command).

Then when the java command is complete, focus is returned to my current window and the macOS current-application-menubar returns to the previous state.

The frequency of that window focus change reminds me of more than one David Lynch production. But the danger is the keyboard focus. One stray keystroke and I get more than a little confused/p*ssed off.

I'd had faint hopes that using `-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=false` would have an unintended but positive side effect but nothing changed.

I've been living with this for quite some time and so I don't know when such behavior might have been introduced. In any case, I'm using macOS 10.13.6 and java 1.8.0_171 and my shell is bash (but no weird aliases or prompts).

Comment: Have you tried `-Djava.awt.headless=true`?

Comment: I just did and it appears to have accomplished what I want. Please provide an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to run disconnected from the local graphics environment.

See [Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html).